# Create a function return in component (grid) Extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a grid panel and i make a function inside that like

```
myFunction: function(variable){ 
    grid.getStore().each(function(item) {
        if (item.get('value') == variable) {
             alert('run'); // running
             return true; // but not return true
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

But when i using

```
alert(grid.myFunction('abc')); // always return false Although alert('run'); running
```

How to fix that thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only returning true inside of the `each` function.  This will break you out of the inner function, but will not return true from the outer function.  To get what you want, you could use a variable that you set outside of `each`, then return that at the end:

```
myFunction: function(variable){
    var found = false;
    grid.getStore().each(function(item) {
        if (item.get('value') == variable) {
            alert('run');
            found = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return found;
}
```

Also note that returning false from `store.each` aborts the iteration, which is what you would want to do after finding your record, so I've added that in there too.  See docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-each